# UITableView loads all the pages of API once

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have UIScrollView inside which there is UITableView. I have implemented the concept of paging by which I request 10 records from web service in each page. I increase the page number in willDisplay delegate method of UITableView like this:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    if self.pageNumber == 0{
        self.pageNumber = 1
    }
    if pageNumber >= self.totalPages{
        return
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.listData?.count)! == 10*pageNumber{
            if (self.listData?.count)! - 1 == indexPath.row{
                pageNumber += 1
                self.callService()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing problem that all the records are loaded once whereas I want all the records to be loaded as user scroll down the UITableView with the increase of page number in above method. Here is callService Method:

func callService(){

```
    ProfileApiStore.shared.requestToGetProfile(loggedInUserId: UserStore.shared.userId, userId:  UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile, limit: "10", page: String(self.pageNumber), completion: {(result) in
        self.totalPages = result.totalPages!
        if self.listData?.count == 0  || (self.pageNumber as AnyObject) as! Int == (1 as AnyObject) as! Int{
            self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData
        } else {
            self.listData = self.listData! +  (result.userdata?.newPostData)!

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: So every time that it loads a single cell you are going to try and load the next page? so when you load the first page, it will load 10 cells... so 10 more pages? then every scroll you do will load more and more. You need to do it a different way (I done it based on scrollOffset). You also shouldn't use a tableView inside a scrollView unless you really know what you are doing, the tableView already uses a scrollView

Comment: As you can see according to this line: if (self.listData?.count)! - 1 == indexPath.row{ the next page should only load when the user has scrolled to second last row of UITableView.

Comment: the title of the question is "UITableView loads all the pages of API once", so its not working as you would expect. how big are the cell heights? how many rows can be displayed on a page? are you dequeueing properly? does screen size affect how many rows are shown at once?, is your service actually paging? how many requests is it making?

Comment: My UITableView cell height is UITableViewAutomaticDimension. 10 records can be displayed on one page. How can I Dequeue? My service is paging. it is requesting 10 records in one page. Screen size does not affect how many recods are shown.

Comment: Please paste your callservice() method

Comment: func callService(){if self.pageNumber == 0{self.pageNumber = 1}
        ProfileApiStore.shared.requestToGetProfile(loggedInUserId: UserStore.shared.userId, userId:  UserStore.shared.userIdToViewProfile, limit: "10", page: String(self.pageNumber), completion: {(result) in
            self.totalPages = result.totalPages!
if self.listData?.count == 0  || (self.pageNumber as AnyObject) as! Int == (1 as AnyObject) as! Int{self.listData = result.userdata?.newPostData } else {
                self.listData = self.listData! +  (result.userdata?.newPostData)!  }
  self.tableView.reloadData() })}

Comment: Sorry, number of characters I could enter was limited.

Comment: please edit the code into your question and format as code so we can read it properly, from what I can see it looks ok, but best to make it part of the question

Comment: I have added the code.